# War card game in javascript/css/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS file: http://useless-r-us.t15.org/projects/war/stylesheet.css
JAVASCRIPT file: http://useless-r-us.t15.org/projects/war/engine.js
The game itself (html code if you view source...): http://useless-r-us.t15.org/projects/war

I was trying to implement a rather simple card game called war in which two players continually flip over their top most card and add both of those cards to the bottom of the deck of the player with the higher card...in the event of a tie they lay 3 cards face-down and then flip the next ones over like a normal turn but with the additional stakes of the other person's 4 more cards.  Anyway...my implementation happens to be absolutely terrible at the moment...and I've been trying to fix it or at least understand what's going wrong...to play click the blue card (you) and it will "flip over" a card for you and your opponent and update the score...my code seems to indicate it would do that...but it doesn't work...half the time it doesn't show the card or shows the broken file image thing...or it just does nothing when I click it...or the score doesn't update...or all three...I've been working on this forever..Thank You so much if you can help :)

Also...Firebug is giving me the error that both your_new_card and opponent_new_card are occasionally undefined...

P.S. (I still have to add the code for what happens when the cards are the same number...right now I have it just give you the card.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in engine.js line 90 i found code with error 
`opponent_array[opponent-size]=value2;` 
and replace with 
`opponent_array[opponent_size]=value2;`

and it works

Comment: Thanks!...but one other error I found with firebug is that after a while it gives the error: your_new_card is undefined...but I can see where I define it...I don't get that...

Answer (score 1):

Install this on Firefox and use it to debug your problem:

http://getfirebug.com/

Firebug is amazing!